# Find equal twin record postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table company with 60 columns. The goal is to create a tool to find, compare and eliminate duplicates in this table.

Example: I have a record with id 22 and I know it has a twin because I run this (simplified code):

```
SELECT min(co_id),co_name,count(*) FROM co
GROUP BY co_name
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

The result shows there are one twin (count 2) and I get the oldest id by min(co_id)

My question is how I search for the twin co_id? Just passing the oldest id?

Something like:

```
SELECT co_id FROM co
WHERE co_name EQUAL TO co_id='22'
LIMIT 2
```

Sample data:

```
id    co_name
22    Volvo
23    Volvo
24    Ford
25    Ford
```

I know id 22 and I want to search for the twin 23 based on the content of 22.

The closest I found is this. Which is far from generic. And a nightmare for comparing 60 field:

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT max(b.id) from co b 
WHERE a.co_name = b.co_name 
LIMIT 1) as twin
FROM co a
WHERE id='22'
```

How do I do this in a more simple and generic way? I just want the twin record co_id.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution that is working on 60 columns if I use variables in stead of hardcode in the query. Thanks everybody for all input. Some of them were about the same track.

```
SELECT id,
(SELECT max(b.id) from co b 
WHERE concat(a.co_name,etc) = concat(b.co_name,etc)
LIMIT 1) as twin
FROM co a
WHERE id='22'
```

Not the best one, but fetch one twin at a time. And it is far from generic. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. A generic solution would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

select max_co,co_name from (
select max(co_id) max_co,min(co_id) min_co,co_name from co 
group by co_name having count(*)>1) where min_co=(your old co id as input);

Answer (score 0):

You can join your table with itself:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM
  co_name c1 INNER JOIN co_name c2
  ON c1.co_name=c2.co_name
     AND c1.id>c2.id
```

this will return all duplicated records (but not the original record with the lowest id). Or since you're using Postgresql you can use a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    co_name,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION by co_name ORDER BY id) as row
  FROM
    co_name
  ) s
WHERE
  row>1;
```

Please see an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5525b/1).

If you want to compare multiple columns, the JOIN solution would be more flexible. I don't know exactly how you want to compare your columns and how you exactly define "twin" rows, but you a query like this should help:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM
  co_name c1 INNER JOIN co_name c2
  ON (
       c1.co_name=c2.co_name
       OR c1.co_city=c2.co_city
       OR c1.co_owner=c2.co_owner
       OR ...
     ) AND c1.id>c2.id
```

if you just want duplicated records of id=22 then you can try with this:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM
  co_name c1 INNER JOIN co_name c2
  ON c1.co_name=c2.co_name
     AND c1.id>c2.id
WHERE
  c2.id=22
```

or if you just want a single twin, comparing 60 columns, you can try with this query:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as Twin /* or MAX(ID), depending what you're after */
FROM
  co_name c1 INNER JOIN co_name c2
  ON (
       c1.co_name=c2.co_name
       OR c1.co_city=c2.co_city
       OR c1.co_owner=c2.co_owner
       OR ...
     ) AND c1.id>c2.id
WHERE
  c2.id=22
```

Comment: Sorry. Both queries gives ALL twins. Not only the desired id 23.

Comment: @sibert they will return both 23 and 25, isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: Only the id that matches 22 = the twin 23.

Comment: @sibert please see my updated answer. What if there are more than two duplicates?

Comment: Yes. And this will list all twins. Not only 23: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0761/18

Comment: This is the best solution so far. But comparing 60 columns... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b0761/23

Comment: @sibert how do you define a twin? you just want the next record that has some common fields with 22? I've added one more query to my answer